How to Save List of Instance(s) Data to File in C#?
I create an engineering program that do some complex calculation (based on Finite-Element Method approach). I obtained the data from another application (AutoCAD & Abaqus) through their API.
After I do some calculation, I want my program to be able to save the calculation result. And therefore it can be opened later when I need it. Currently, the simplified data structure is as follow:
class TitaniumBar
{
    //The data below is obtained from another program through API
    public Dictionary<int,int> Coordinate { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<double, double>> ExternalStress { get; set; }

    //The data below is obtained after performing complex calculation in my software
    public double StressRatio { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<long, long[]> ConnectivityData;

    public TitaniumBar()
    {
        Coordinate = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        ExternalStress = new();
        ConnectivityData = new();
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    public static List<TitaniumBar> TitaniumBars { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TitaniumBars = new List<TitaniumBar>();
        for (int i = 0; i<50; i++)
        {
            //This data is actually obtained from another program
            TitaniumBar bar = new TitaniumBar();
            bar.Coordinate.Add(1, 2);
            Dictionary<double, double> StressData1 = new Dictionary<double, double>() { { 9.5685, 123.123 } };
            Dictionary<double, double> StressData2 = new Dictionary<double, double>() { { 7.366915, 4.59623 } };
            bar.ExternalStress.Add("S1", StressData1);
            bar.ExternalStress.Add("S2", StressData2);

            //The data below is actually obtained after performing complex calulation
            bar.StressRatio = 0.9599;
            bar.ConnectivityData.Add(14, new long[] {1,3,4,5});

            TitaniumBars.Add(bar);
        }
        
    }
}

I have a class called TitaniumBar which have the data that I get from the another program thourgh API call ("Coordinate" and "ExternalStress"), and I have calculation result (StressRatio and ConnectivityData)
There will be a lot of bars that I need to calculate. In the example code above, I just give exmample of 50 bars data. The "bar" data will be stored to a list called TitaniumBars
I want to store/export the data of TitaniumBars list to a file, where I can open/use it again later. Could you provide suggestion what should I do in order to save the data to a file?
Note:
I do not want to use database that require SQL server which is quite complex when I need to distribute my program to my other colleagues.
I heard json or xml serializer can also do it. But is there any other alternative to do it?
I heard that it can be done using entity database. But I am not sure if entity database let me save the file without having running sql server first on my computer. (I do not want to run sql server on my computer since I will distribute the program to many other people)

I would store the data as JSON. You can serialize your property and save it to a file. Later you can read the file content and deserialize it again.

Is there any other alternative than JSON? Since the data will be huge  and it may be up to 30000 data entries. I believe using JSON will result in a very large file. and it will be slow when loading again to my application.

You can use any text format you like to, e.g. XML. You could even implement your own "datatype" with its own format. But I would not recommend it. I made very good experience with JSON. Its overhead is very small compared to XML. I do not think you are getting huge performance issues with 30000 data entries if each entry is not that huge.
